# How to stop a thread in python and continue it after a specific time?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, synchronization

I am creating an MP3 music player with lyrics synchronization feature. I want to stop the synchronization of lyrics when the user presses on the pause button (tkinter). The code looks like this:

```
    def highlightlyrics():
            a=threading.Thread(target=SyncLyrics)
            a.start()
        # code of lyrics synchronization
    def SyncLyrics():
        global playing
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        try:
            # this if statement is for when the user uploads an lrc
            if playing and TimePlaying_value>=1:
                NoToRoundOff=TimePlaying_value
                    # list contains the nearest lyrics timestamps to the time of the song 
                dictionary=[]
                    # this list contains the position of timestamps
                pos=[]
                    # this for loop is for finding the nearest lyrics of timestamps of the song
                for x in range(len(LYRICS)):
                    if times[x]-NoToRoundOff>0:
                        dictionary.append(times[x]-NoToRoundOff)
                        pos.append(x)
                        ls.select_set(min(pos)-2)
                        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
                        break
                # this for loop is for continuation of synchronization          
                for x in range(min(pos),len(LYRICS)):
                    ls.select_clear(x-1)
                    ls.select_set(x)
                    time.sleep(float((format(times[x+1]-times[x],'.2f'))))
        except Exception as e:
                raise e
                thread._stop() 

#I tried to create a variable where a Boolean value is stored when the user #clicks on the pause button the variable data goes to true
        #The code i tried to fix this:
     
        def change():
            global is_paused
            if PlayButton['image']==str(PLay):
                pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
                PlayButton['image']=PAuse
                PlayButton.pack()
                is_paused=False
            else:
                pygame.mixer.music.pause()
                PlayButton['image']=PLay
                PlayButton.pack()
                is_paused=True
        def SyncLyrics():
            global playing
            pygame.mixer.music.pause()
            try:
                # this if statement is for when the user uploads [lyrics ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LRC_(file_format)) file after the song is started
                if playing and TimePlaying_value>=1:
                    NoToRoundOff=TimePlaying_value
                    # list contains the nearest lyrics timestamps to the time of the song 
                    dictionary=[]
                    # this list contains the position of timestamps
                    pos=[]
                    # this for loop is for finding the nearest lyrics of timestamps of the song
                    if not is_paused:
                        for x in range(len(LYRICS)):
                            if times[x]-NoToRoundOff>0:
                                dictionary.append(times[x]-NoToRoundOff)
                                pos.append(x)
                                ls.select_set(min(pos)-2)
                                pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
                                break
                                for x in range(min(pos),len(LYRICS)):
                                     ls.select_clear(x-1)
                                     ls.select_set(x)
                                     time.sleep(float((format(times[x+1]-times[x],'.2f'))))
                    else:
                        pass
                print(is_paused)# When I clicked on the pause button it shows me the output as false. But it had to give true.
                # this for loop is for continuation of synchronization          
                for x in range(min(pos),len(LYRICS)):
                    ls.select_clear(x-1)
                    ls.select_set(x)
                    time.sleep(float((format(times[x+1]-times[x],'.2f'))))
            except Exception as e:
                raise e
                thread._stop()
```

The main problem of the code is that the is_paused variable doesn't gets update to true when i click on paused button
If you have understood the question please answer. IF you have any type of query comment it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pause and resume a thread using the threading module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262346/how-to-pause-and-resume-a-thread-using-the-threading-module)

Comment: The `is_paused` variable is modified in the method `change`, but a quick search of your code for any reference to the name `change` turns up nothing.  So it appears that this function never runs.  Perhaps you left out something.